# SQL JOIN not filtering correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My SQL statement was showing the data properly until I added the last two `JOIN` statements. I need to somehow properly "link" them to the data.

My statement:

```
FROM dbo.DailyWork AS dw
LEFT JOIN dbo.Labor as lab
ON dw.DailyWorkID=LAB.DailyWorkID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Company AS com
ON dw.CompanyID=com.CompanyID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Projects AS proj
ON dw.ProjectID=proj.ProjectID
JOIN dbo.LU_Trade AS trade
ON lab.TradeID=lab.TradeID
JOIN dbo.LU_Classification as class
ON lab.ClassID=class.ClassID
```

**Relevant tables:**

**Dailywork**

```
SELECT [DailyWorkID]
      ,[Date]
      ,[CompanyID]
      ,[CrewID]
      ,[WorkDescription]
      ,[LastModified]
      ,[LastModifiedBy]
      ,[ProjectID]
      ,[GUID]
      ,[IsClosed]
      ,[TypeID]
      ,[CategoryID]
      ,[Status]
      ,[IsFromCrewSight]
  FROM [dbo].[DailyWork]
```

**Labor**

```
SELECT [LaborID]
      ,[DailyWorkID]
      ,[EmployeeID]
      ,[StartTime]
      ,[BreakTime]
      ,[FinishTime]
      ,[STQty]
      ,[OTQty]
      ,[DTQty]
      ,[TotalSTQty]
      ,[TotalOTQty]
      ,[TotalDTQty]
      ,[CostCodeReference]
      ,[Notes]
      ,[TradeID]
      ,[ClassID]
      ,[ManpowerQty]
      ,[UOM]
      ,[TotalManQtyPerCrew]
      ,[TotalManQtyPerCompany]
      ,[TotalManpowerQty]
      ,[SortOrder]
      ,[LastModified]
      ,[LastModifiedBy]
      ,[ProjectID]
      ,[GUID]
      ,[IsFromCrewSight]
  FROM [dbo].[Labor]
```

**LU_Trade**

```
SELECT [TradeID]
      ,[Description]
      ,[UserText1]
      ,[UserNum1]
      ,[SortOrder]
  FROM [dbo].[LU_Trade]
```

**LU_Classification**

```
SELECT [ClassID]
      ,[Description]
      ,[UserText1]
      ,[UserNum1]
      ,[SortOrder]
  FROM [dbo].[LU_Classification]
```

My first thought is that I should have used dbo.Labor as my `FROM` statement because it combines most of the columns. However, I still don't know how to "link" the Trade and Classification to the logic.

Comment: `...JOIN dbo.LU_Trade AS trade
ON lab.TradeID=lab.TradeID...`  This is a typo - your join condition is using the same column on both sides.

Comment: Fixed that in the re-write. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with what you are joining on. Initially you had Labor Left Joined to DailyWork. The nature of the left join is to only bring back additional data and keep rows of DailyWork that don't match anything on the Labor table.

When you added the last two tables, you used `JOIN` which is equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`. When the query tried to join on the `NULL` values generated by the `LEFT JOIN` of the Labor table, those rows dropped out.

If you changed the last two joins in your original query to use a `LEFT JOIN` like below, you should get the correct rows.

```
FROM dbo.DailyWork AS dw
LEFT JOIN dbo.Labor as lab
ON dw.DailyWorkID=LAB.DailyWorkID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Company AS com
ON dw.CompanyID=com.CompanyID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Projects AS proj
ON lab.ProjectID=proj.ProjectID
LEFT JOIN dbo.LU_Trade AS trade
ON lab.TradeID=trade.TradeID
LEFT JOIN dbo.LU_Classification as class
ON lab.ClassID=class.ClassID
```

On a side note, if your first two tables are interchangeable, do you need to use left joins for all of the tables that follow?

Comment: I tried adding a `LEFT JOIN` for the last two items, that didn't work. However, the new `JOIN` statement I wrote in the Answers seems to be working. I just revised it, and only kept the `LEFT JOIN` on the first `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the `JOIN` statement to be based on the Labor table. It seems to have fixed it.

```
FROM dbo.Labor as lab
LEFT JOIN dbo.DailyWork AS dw
ON lab.DailyWorkID=dw.DailyWorkID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Company AS com
ON dw.CompanyID=com.CompanyID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Projects AS proj
ON lab.ProjectID=proj.ProjectID
JOIN dbo.LU_Trade AS trade
ON lab.TradeID=trade.TradeID
JOIN dbo.LU_Classification as class
ON lab.ClassID=class.ClassID
```

Now I'm curious, is the only way to combine information from different tables, is to have a table to combines **all** the columns ?

Comment: I doubt this query is identical to the one above even if the results are the same (for now). Repeating the above answerer: when you start a branch of left joins you need to continue with left joins. It's also possible to use parenthesis to change the join order and sometimes right joins come in handy in complicated scenarios. I suspect you don't quite see what the the left joins are actually doing.

Comment: Do you have an example that depicts the need to continue `LEFT JOIN`S along a branch? I'm not doubting you, I just can't imagine a case to prove it to my self.

Comment: Well suppose you have customers with orders and orders have line items. Now for some reason you want a report showing customers, even those without orders, while also including a total of items purchased or something. If you don't continue the left join to the line items table you'll lose the customers you intended to keep.

Comment: Now with parens you could change the join outer so the orders and line items are linked up first which eliminates the problem (assuming line items aren't optional.) Or you could do the inner join and then add customers as a right join but nobody ever does that.